# Compass $default-animation-duration not being used?

Tags: css, animation, sass, compass-sass

I recently updated to Compass version 1.0.16 and am setting up basic use of the new animation stuff. For some reason, when I try to set the default values for different animation settings, they don't take effect, requiring that I hard-code the values throughout my app.

Specifically:

```
$default-animation-duration: 0.5s;

@import "compass/css3";

@include keyframes(slideOutLeft) {
    0% {
        @include transform(translateX(0%));
    }

    100% {
        @include transform(translateX(-100%));
    }
}

#id {
    @include animation(slideOutLeft); // Doesn't work
}

#id2 {
    @include animation(slideOutLeft 0.5s); // Does work.
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official word from the Compass folks can be found here: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1556

> Yeah, currently the defaults are only used in the long-form properties
>   e.g. animation-duration(), or in when no arguments other are passed
>   e.g. animation() (where all the defaults are used). Not sure that's
>   the best way, but the defaults are pretty invasive otherwise.